# GPL Ghostscript build mac os x framework from source error?

Tags: macos, ghostscript

I download the GPL Ghsotscript9.00 from sourceforge.net, and try to bulid source as framework in mac, the steps as the help document about make, such as: copy macosx.mak to the top-level directory, rename it to makefile and issue 'make framework' from Terminal.app. then the procedure ends with this:

```
./base/gsicc_create.c: At top level:
./base/gsicc_create.c:242: warning: ‘gsicc_diagmatrix_init’ defined but not used
./base/gsicc_create.c:294: warning: ‘cie_is_lab’ defined but not used
./base/gsicc_create.c:542: warning: ‘swapbytes32’ defined but not used
./base/gsicc_create.c:692: warning: ‘add_desc_tag’ defined but not used
./base/gsicc_create.c:714: warning: ‘add_text_tag’ defined but not used
./base/gsicc_create.c:1382: warning: ‘add_tabledata’ defined but not used
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `obj/../soobj/lcms.dev', needed by `obj/../soobj/sicclib.dev'.  Stop.
make: *** [so] Error 2
```

I don't know why the official file can't work? Maybe there are some operations I need to do before making, but how? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the latest 9.04 from http://www.ghostscript.com/download (this is the top level page, actual
source download from http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ghostscript-9.04.tar.gz )

If you continue to have problems, please post the issue at http://bugs.ghostscript.com

We have several Artifex staff developers that work on macosx that build regularly, but they may not build the
shared obj lib regularly.